# Could I use method call from mounted function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Could I use method call from mounted function?

in my code, I used this method.

```
mounted() {
    this.initEvent();
    this.getnewD(
    $(function () {
      $("#file-manager").dxFileManager({
        name: "fileManager",
        fileSystemProvider: customProvider,
        currentPath: "Documents",
        rootFolderName: "Root",
        height: 450,
        onErrorOcurred: function (e) {
          debugger;
          console.log(e);
        },
        permissions: {
          create: true,
          copy: true,
          move: true,
          delete: true,
          rename: true,
        },
        customizeDetailColumns: (columns) => {
          columns.push({
            caption: "Creator",
            dataField: "dataItem.creator",
          });
          return columns;
        },
      });
    }));
  },
```

And in my methods, I tried to used this methods to call mounted function.
But I got the customProvider is not a function.
So where has problem in my code?

```
methods: {
arr.forEach((item) => {
              let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
              let current = tree;
              for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
                  current[tokens[i]] = {};
                }
                current = current[tokens[i]];
              }
            });
            const parseNode = function (node) {
              return Object.keys(node).map((key) => {
                if (Object.keys(node[key]).length === 0) {
                  return {
                    isDirectory: false,
                    name: key,
                  };
                }
                return {
                  isDirectory: true,
                  name: key,
                  items: parseNode(node[key]),
                };
              });
            };
            let result = parseNode(tree);

var objectProvider =
              new DevExpress.fileManagement.ObjectFileSystemProvider({
                data: new_r,
              });
            var customProvider =
              new DevExpress.fileManagement.CustomFileSystemProvider({
                getItems: function (pathInfo) {
                  return objectProvider.getItems(pathInfo);
                },
                renameItem: function (item, name) {
                  if (item.name == "Parent1") {
                    console.log("error in custom provider");
                    throw {
                      errorId: 0,
                      fileItem: item,
                    };
                    console.log("error in custom provider");
                  } else return objectProvider.renameItem(item, name);
                },
                createDirectory: function (parentDir, name) {
                  if (parentDir.name == "Parent1") {
                    throw {
                      errorId: 0,
                      fileItem: item,
                    };
                  } else return objectProvider.createDirectory(parentDir, name);
                },
                deleteItem: function (item) {
                  console.log(item);
                  if (item.name == "Parent1") {
                    throw {
                      errorId: 0,
                      fileItem: item,
                    };
                  } else return objectProvider.deleteItems([item]);
                },
                moveItem: function (item, destinationDir) {
                  if (item.name == "Parent1") {
                    throw {
                      errorId: 0,
                      fileItem: item,
                    };
                  } else
                    return objectProvider.moveItems([item], destinationDir);
                },
                copyItem: function (item, destinationDir) {
                  if (item.name == "Parent1") {
                    throw {
                      errorId: 0,
                      fileItem: item,
                    };
                  } else
                    return objectProvider.copyItems([item], destinationDir);
                },
              });
            let new_r = (self.fileSystemProvider = [
              {
                name: "Security Manager",
                isDirectory: true,
                items: result,
              },
            ]);
}
```

I could got the data, but couldn't got some function and displayed the customProvider is not a function.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you provided.

Comment: arr.forEach( is not a named function

Comment: You need something like that:

`methods: {
myfunction(items) {
items.forEach((item) => {

...
}`

Somewhere else call `myfunction(arr)`

Answer (score 0):

This has no proper function name in methods: { }

```
arr.forEach((item) => { ... }
```

Your methods need to be named!

You need something like that in your `methods:` object:

```
methods: {
  myfunction(items) {
    items.forEach((item) => {    
    ...
  }
}
```

Now you can call `myfunction(arr)`  somewhere else in your script tags

mounted() works with plain js code inside because it is a named lifecycle hook. The methods: { } object however is not a function.